# RoomDB cannot convert type Map<String, List<Int>> even with Type converter. Android/Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room

I tried saving a Map<String, List> to my database, added a type converter to it but its still not working.  This is the error I am getting

```
error: Query method parameters should either be a type that can be converted into a database column or a List / Array that contains such type. You can consider adding a Type Adapter for this.
    java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>> colorLabels, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

This is my entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "images")
@TypeConverters(ImageTypeConverters::class)
data class CBImageDataModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long = 0,
    ...
    val colors: Map<String, ColorModel>,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "color_labels") val colorLabels: Map<String, List<Int>>? = null
)
```

This is my query

```
    @Query("UPDATE images SET color_labels = :colorLabels  WHERE id =:id")
    suspend fun updateProgressImage(
        id: Long,
        colorLabels: Map<kotlin.String, List<Int>>
    )
```

And this is my type converter

```
class ImageTypeConverters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toColorMap(string: String?): Map<String, ColorModel> {
        val gson = Gson()
        val myType = object : TypeToken<Map<String, ColorModel>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson<Map<String, ColorModel>>(string, myType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromColorMap(colors: Map<String, ColorModel>?): String? {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(colors)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toColorLabelMap(string: String?): Map<String, List<Int>?>? {
        val gson = Gson()
        val myType = object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<Int>?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(string, myType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromColorLabelMap(colors: Map<String, List<Int>?>?): String? {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(colors)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toListInt(string: String?): List<Int>? {
        val gson = Gson()
        val myType = object : TypeToken<List<Int> >() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson<List<Int> >(string, myType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromListInt(listInt : List<Int>?): String? {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(listInt)
    }
}
```

I tried adding nullable types and removing nullability, played around with values and stuff but I cannot figure out what is happening. I do have all the type converters in place but I must've setup something incorrectly. I tried restarting, rebuilding, cleaning the project.

SOLUTION: After adding the converter to at the top of the `abstract class AppDatabse : RoomDatabse()` it works. Idk why it works like that, I already had the converter added to the entity but it seems this has to be done as well

I'll leave it to someone to explain why this has to be done, so future people can understand the problem better

Comment: Try replacing `colorLabels: Map<kotlin.String, List<Int>>` with `colorLabels: Map<String, List<Int>>` and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah, same result. I played with those imports as the error is stating java.utils.Map. So I checked if something was improperly imported but that's not the case. I am using Kotlin.collections and Kotlin.string everywhere